# I need a variable that references all of the select objects

Tags: javascript

I have a form with several select objects, they each have a different id's but the same class name.  I need a variable that references all of the select objects.  So far I have just found where you can reference a single form element.
This would be for JavaScript.

This is in my .js file

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var allSelect = document.govLinks.querySelectorAll('select');

    for (var i = 0; i < allSelect.length; i++){
       allSelect[i].onchange = function() {
           var selectIndex = allSelect[i].selectedIndex;
          window.location.href = allSelect[i].options[selectIndex].value;
        }
    }   
});
```

This is in my html file.

```
<article>
   <form id="govLinks" name="govLinks">
   <h1>Government Sites on the Web</h1>
     <p>Select a site from one of the drop-down lists below.</p>
     <table>
     <tr><td>Executive Branch</td>
         <td><select name="executive" id="executive" class="optionLinks">
            <option value="#">Select a Web site</option>
            <option value="http://www.whitehouse.gov">The House</option>
            <option value="http://www.usda.gov">Dept of Agriculture</option>
          </select>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td>Legislative Branch</td>
        <td><select name="legislative" id="legislative" class="optionLinks">
            <option value="#">Select a Web site</option>
            <option value="http://www.house.gov">House Web Site</option>
            <option value="http://www.senate.gov">Senate Web Site</option>
      </select>
       </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </form>     
  </article>
```

Comment: so could I do the following using your example. 
var myVar = document.querySelectorAll('select.my-select');
and then to use it, myVar[index], to get a specific one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
Now that you added your code and desired behaviour. You can use `this.value` inside the change handler to get the selected value from the clicked option.

```
var allSelect = document.govLinks.querySelectorAll('select');

    for (var i = 0; i < allSelect.length; i++){
       allSelect[i].onchange = function() {
          window.location.href = this.value;
        }
    }
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sygn/yej8oqqx/1/)

You can use `document.getElementsByTagName('select')` or `document.querySelectorAll('.yourClassName')` or `document.getElementsByClassName('yourClassName')`.

More info about getElementsByTagName [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

More info about getElementsByClassName [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

More info about querySelectorAll [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: Trying 
var mySelect = document.myform.querySelectorAll('select');
But then need do loop through and get the value of what was selected.

for (var i = 0; i < mylSelect.length; i++){
    mylSelect[i].onchange = function() {
      var selectIndex = mylSelect[i].selectedIndex;
      window.location.href = mylSelect[i].options[selectIndex].value;
  }
 } 
But it doesn't work.

Comment: you didn;t mention that part in your question, all of those return a collection of matched elements, add your html and update your question

Answer (score 0):

Use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('select.my-select').forEach(function(el, i){       
   console.log('Id of select.my-select at index', i, 'is:', el.id)
})
```

```html
<select id="sel_1" class="my-select"></select>
<select id="sel_2" class="my-select"></select>
<select id="sel_3" class="my-select"></select>
```

Answer (score -3):

I am not too sure about JavaScript having that. You could use the jQuery .class selector for your purposes.

For example -

```
$(".class").append("YOU CAN APPEND THIS TEXT TO EVERY ELEMENT IN THE CLASS 
CLASS. YAY!");
```

Sorry....I don't think it works in JS